# How can I know how long a socket connection(tcp or udp) has been established in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, networking

I want to know how long a socket connection has last in linux, or when a socket connection has been established ,  any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this similar question in Super User http://superuser.com/questions/565991/how-to-determine-the-socket-connection-up-time-on-linux

Comment: yes, the same question .but there is  no right answer.

Comment: Aw yes you're right I though the answer was ok :( My second guess was related to getting the PID of the process and the file descriptor of the socket with `lsof -iTCP` and then using `stat /proc/<pid>/fd/<socket_file_descriptor>`, which gives you some timestamps (atime, mtime, ctime), but I'm not sure if those are reliable.

Comment: We might be able to help more if you mentioned *why* you need that kind of information...

Comment: @javidcf: on my system those times equal the system boot time, which is completely useless...

Comment: @javidcf timestamps (atime, mtime, ctime) doesn't help, in some way, I want to know the create-time of the fd .

Comment: @thkala , I have a game server, but I found there are  some connections which were in `ESTABLISHED` for a long time by `netstat`, even if in midnight . Because we don't have `keep alive` and server won't close even if they don't connect for a long time , I think those connections  may be "zombie".So I want to know how long a socket connection has last

Answer (score 4):

This may be a bit more performance heavy and manual than you hoped for... but... One possibility is to log new connections with iptables and cross reference the ip/port combination from the log and the kernel log.

Enabling connection logging using iptables:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "New Connection: "
iptables -I OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "New Connection: "
```

Look for current connection:

```
# netstat -an
...
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:38272         74.125.143.99:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:41289         173.194.71.94:80        TIME_WAIT  
...
```

Then it is possible to check for a log in /var/log/kern.log to get the socket init. Below I grep for the client port since it is the most signifying number.

```
# grep 41289 /var/log/kern.log
Oct 12 01:24:24 hamilton kernel: [49068.994676] New Connection: IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=173.194.71.94 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=48013 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41289 DPT=80 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```